# Как дать команду гит, чтобы можно было удалить добавленные файлы(убрать из отслеживание)?

Tags: git

Представим ситуацию, когда нам нужно добавить новый файл в проект, как себя ведет `Git`(это вопрос 1.0)
А если их очень много  (условно), но нам сказали, эту задачу больше не нужно выполнять. Мы решили избавиться от этих добавленных файлов.
Может ли  `Git` убрать эти файлы или вообще удалить их(это вопрос 1.1)
Конечно,  мы можем и ничто  не мешает в ручную сделать, но опять же файлов очень много, и искать файлы может занять много времени.

***Resourse:***

**For Example**

Структура проекта, начальное состояние

```
.git
build/
fonts/
src/
.gitignore
package.json
package-lock.json
```

Теперь добавляем, новые файлы и даже фолдеры

```
.git
build/
fonts/
src/
.gitignore
package.json
package-lock.json
somefolder/ // добавлена новая папка
somefiles1 // добавлен новый файл  == вот как раз таки от них нужно избавиться с помощью Git
somefiles2 // добавлен еще новый файл
```

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Вы спрашиваете как добавлять и удалять файлы из Git?

Comment: Например, в проект случайно добавил 100 файлов, и гит заметил это, но как гит  сможет стереть и вернуть в предыдущее состояние, чтоб эти файлы исчезли, как будто их и не было.  P.S опять же я могу это сделать в ручную. Но есть возможность сделать это с помощью гит

Comment: `$ git clean -fx`

Comment: Чувак спасибо, отлично! Теперь напоследок, подскажи, а как в определенный директории и 
определенный  файл убрать?
аналогия когда убираешь из изменения:  git checkout -- resource/some-folder/inner-folder/file.js